# reCaptcha not shows on my singlepage website

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, recaptcha

I have some problem with the recaptcha loading.

I trying to remake and modernize one of old my website to a singlepage one with php, javascript and ajax (no jquery!).

Everyting is fine yet, but the recaptca. I use the following method.

1. `index.php` contains the "main frame" and the target divs to the HTTPRequest function.
2. With AJAX I load the PHP page templates to the main target divs.

BUT when my PHP template file looks the following to show the registration last page with the captcha:

```
<?php

$template = '

.../ some code sits here /...

<div class="w80">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=".../ my sitekey sits here /..."></div>
</div>
<div class="flex-row fr-c mt50a">
    <button class="button btn-reg" onclick="switchPage(\'registration_page_2.php\')">&laquo; Back</button>
    <button class="button btn-reg" onclick="validatePage(\'registration_validate.php\')">Submit your registration</button>
</div>
';

echo $template;
```

and I load it into one of my `div`s, the reCaptcha has not been shown. I tried some ways and tricks, but it's not working.

There is no form and submit section at all on my page. I do it with javascript and ajax.

Why I cannot make it works? 
Is that possible to bypass form->submit->post method to get reCaptcha alive? 
Or is the singlepage the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand you but since i can't post a comment, i will attempt to answer anyway.

You don't have to use php to echo the html code, just in-case you didn't know, you can do it like this.

```
<?php
//php code
?>
<div class="w80">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=".../ my sitekey sits here /..."></div>
</div>
<div class="flex-row fr-c mt50a">
    <button class="button btn-reg" onclick="switchPage('registration_page_2.php')">&laquo; Back</button>
    <button class="button btn-reg" onclick="validatePage('registration_validate.php')">Submit your registration</button>
</div>
<?php //continue code here ?>
```

> and I load it into one of my divs, the reCaptcha has not been shown. I
>   tried some ways and tricks, but its not works :(

It's hard to tell from the information you have given why it is not being shown

> There is no form and submit section at all on my page. I do it with
>   javascript and ajax.

If your registration_page_2.php and registration_validate.php does not echo the template in your current .php shown, then it certainly wouldn't appear on your page

> Why I cannot make it works? Is that possible to bypass
>   form->submit->post method to get reCaptcha alive? Or is the singlepage
>   the wrong way?

I think you just did something wrong in the middle. The way you have said is 'form->submit->post' is the right way to go about this

> Can you help me to get the solution please?

Using your browser, inspect or view the source code of your page. (For google chrome the hotkey is CTRL+SHIFT+I) Try to find the elements in your page to see if they are loaded, but hidden due to css or the likes. After which, you should give more details.

Comment: Thank you for the info about the echo. As you said I did not know it. But my problem is still here. I know about the code inspection. I almost alway use it in the debug process, if it realy needs. But in here its not help.

Answer (score 0):

update your captcha block with adding id `recaptcha`

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" id="recaptcha" data-sitekey=".../ my sitekey sits here /..."></div>
```

add following code in your page load

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en&render=explicit&onload=onReCaptchaLoad'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var recaptcha;
var onReCaptchaLoad = function(){
    recaptcha = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha',{
        'sitekey' : 'YOUR_RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY',
        'theme' : 'white'
    });
};
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, its not works in here. And what is you said at your first answare is for the POST type process. There is no Submit->POST in my website, therefore I cannot use your solution. It is works my site old version with the normal method, but not here.

As I guess, the problem is when I load the captcha section with HTTPRequest. In the code inspection it looks it is not the same code when I use the normal HTML method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with php request

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
    $recaptcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $recaptcha_secret = 'YOUR_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY'
    $verify = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={$recaptcha_secret}&response={$recaptcha}");
    $captcha_success = json_decode($verify);
    if($captcha_success->success){
        // success
    }else{
        // error
    }
}
?>
```